# Relay mutation fragments intersection

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay

I don't use Relay container, because I'd like to have more control over components. Instead of it I use HOC + `Relay.Store.forceFetch`, that fetches any given query with variables. So I have the following query:

```
query {
    root {
      search(filter: $filter) {
        selectors {
          _id,
          data {
            title,
            status
          }
        },
        selectorGroups {
          _id,
          data {
            title,
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Then I have to do some mutation on `selector` type.

```
export default class ChangeStatusMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation {selectors_status_mutation}`;
  }
  getVariables() {
    return {
      id: this.props.id,
      status: this.props.status
    };
  }
  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on selectors_status_mutationPayload{
        result {
          data {
            status
          }
        }
      }
    `;
  }
  static fragments = {
    result: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on selector {
        _id,
        data {
          title,
          status
        }
      }`,
  };

  getOptimisticResponse() {
    return {
      result: {
        _id: this.props.id,
        data: {
          status: this.props.status
        }
      }
    };
  }

  getConfigs() {
    return [{
      type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
      fieldIDs: {
        result: this.props.id
      },
    }];
  }
}
```

Call mutation in component:

```
const mutation = new ChangeStatusMutation({id, status, result: selector});
Relay.Store.commitUpdate(mutation);
```

After mutation commitment selector in Relay storage is not changed. I guess that's because of empty `Tracked Fragment Query` and mutation performs without any fields:

```
ChangeStatusMutation($input_0:selectors_statusInput!) {
  selectors_status_mutation(input:$input_0) {
    clientMutationId
  }
}
```

But the modifying selector was already fetched by Relay, and I pass it to the mutation with props. So Relay knows the type, that should be changed, how to find the item and which fields should be replaced. But can not intersect. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So, you're definitely a bit "off the ranch" here by avoiding Relay container, but I think this should still work...

Relay performs the query intersection by looking up the node indicated by your `FIELDS_CHANGE` config. In this case, your `fieldIDs` points it at the  `result` node with ID `this.props.id`.

Are you sure you have a node with that ID in your store? I'm noticing that in your `forceFetch` query you fetch some kind of alternative `_id` but not actually fetching `id`. Relay requires an `id` field to be present on anything that you later want to refetch or use the declarative mutation API on...

I'd start by checking the query you're sending to fetch whatever this `result` type is. I don't see you fetching that anywhere in your question description, so I'm just assuming that maybe you aren't fetching that right now?

Comment: I came across ID field in many relay examples, but never seen, that it's mandatory( I'll try, thanks for aiming

Comment: As about `result` field, you are right it was not requested exactly at the same way, but type of the `result` is `selector` and selectors were requested in the first big query `selectors { ...` So should field names be exactly the same for proper intersection? Because being based on types, it's possible to intersect actually

Comment: The intersection is based on the id, not the field name. That's why you need to make sure you provide it (and give a valid, existing id to the fieldIDs)